# Notifications are not navigating as intended

Tags: flutter, push-notification

I am utilizing FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin to send notifications to the user on my mobile app with the intentions of navigating the user to the homepage when it is pressed during the onboarding process. The notification shows up as intended on the notification test page but when the user presses the notification they are still presented the notification test page. When the app runs in the background as well and I send the notification they are navigated to the test page. However whenever I restart the app from that point (Note: not with the hot reload) I am brought to the homepage.

Here is my current set up I have a notification page in which the user allows notifications and are prompted with this notification

```
`GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () async {
                      print(
                          "Sending notification from Permission folder"); // Debug print
                      HapticFeedback.heavyImpact();
                      const AndroidNotificationDetails
                          androidPlatformChannelSpecifics =
                          AndroidNotificationDetails(
                              'channel_id', 'channel_name',
                              importance: Importance.max,
                              priority: Priority.high,
                              showWhen: false);
                      const NotificationDetails platformChannelSpecifics =
                          NotificationDetails(
                              android: androidPlatformChannelSpecifics);
                      await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
                          0,
                          'keepUp',
                          'your first keepUp Notification',
                          platformChannelSpecifics,
                          payload: 'KEEPUP_NOTI');
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        AwesomePageRoute(
                          transitionDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 600),
                          exitPage: widget,
                          enterPage: NotifcationTest(
                            flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin:
                                flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin,
                          ),
                          transition: ZoomOutSlideTransition(),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                    child: Container(
                      width: 260,
                      height: 40,
                      color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 120, 232),
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: const Text(
                        "Allow",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontSize: 16,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      ),
                    )),`
```

I then have a notification test page in which the user can resend the notification like so

`onPressed: () async { print("Sending notification"); // Debug print const AndroidNotificationDetails androidPlatformChannelSpecifics = AndroidNotificationDetails( 'your_channel_id', 'your_channel_name', importance: Importance.max, priority: Priority.high, showWhen: false); const DarwinNotificationDetails iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics = DarwinNotificationDetails(); // Add iOS specific details here const NotificationDetails platformChannelSpecifics = NotificationDetails( android: androidPlatformChannelSpecifics, iOS: iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics); // Include iOS details await widget.flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show( 0, 'keepUp', '${state.profileUserModel?.displayName} time to keepUp', platformChannelSpecifics, payload: 'KEEPUP_NOTI'); },`

and in my main.dart I deal with the notifications like so,

```
final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
    FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey =
    GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(); // Added

Future<void> setupLocalNotifications() async {
  print("Initializing local notifications");
  const AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid =
      AndroidInitializationSettings('app_icon');

  // Define notification categories for iOS/macOS
  final DarwinInitializationSettings initializationSettingsDarwin =
      DarwinInitializationSettings(
    notificationCategories: [
      DarwinNotificationCategory(
        'KEEPUP_NOTI_CATEGORY',
        actions: <DarwinNotificationAction>[
          DarwinNotificationAction.plain(
            'apply',
            'Apply',
            options: <DarwinNotificationActionOption>{
              DarwinNotificationActionOption.foreground,
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
    ],
  );

  final InitializationSettings initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(
      android: initializationSettingsAndroid,
      iOS: initializationSettingsDarwin);

  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings,
      onDidReceiveNotificationResponse: (NotificationResponse response) async {
    print("Notification tapped!");
    final String? payload = response.payload;
    if (payload != null && payload == 'KEEPUP_NOTI') {
      print('notification payload: $payload');
      navigatorKey.currentState!.pushReplacement(
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage()),
      );
    }
  });
}
```

Some debugging issues `print("Notification tapped!");`, `print('notification payload: $payload');` these two print statements are never called but the `print("Initializing local notifications");` is printed to the debug console when the app first launches. For reference I am testing on an IOS physical device notifications do show up but the navigation when pressed does not work as intended. Please let me know if more information is needed.